# How to select unknown numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, get, element

So for example I have:

array(`2`,`1`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`)

and **I already know** (`2`,`1`,`3`)

How should I get (`4`,`5`,`6`, `7`) if I know that all numbers exists from `1` to `7` and the numbers what **I already know**

So I want an array with the numbers what I don't know yet.

Sorry if sounds stupid :|

Comment: what do you mean 1,2,3? what exactly are we talking about? `<span>1</span>` or... just random chunks of text on the page? give us some sample HTML.

Comment: Are they just arbitrarily scattered throughout the document or are they sibling nodes? It makes a huge difference.

Comment: It can be anything, in this case simple numbers are perfect too. Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

If A = `(2, 1, 3)` and B = `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`

Then do you want the uncommon elements (i.e., elements not existing in either)? You can try this:

```
//note: could be improved - wrote it quickly
function uncommon(a, b) {

    var map = {};
    var alreadyAdded = {};
    var uncommonElements = [];

    var arrays = (a.length > b.length) ? 
                     {first: b, second: a} : 
                     {first: a, second: b};

    for(var i = 0; i < arrays.first.length; i++) {
        map[arrays.first[i]] = true;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < arrays.second.length; i++) {
        if(!map[arrays.second[i]]) {
            uncommonElements.push(arrays.second[i]);
            alreadyAdded[arrays.second[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < arrays.first.length; i++) {
        if(!map[arrays.second[i]] && !alreadyAdded[arrays.first[i]]) {
            uncommonElements.push(arrays.first[i]);
        }
    }

    return uncommonElements;
}
```

Also note that if you had:

A = `(2, 1, 3, 9)` and B = `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`, you would get `(2, 1, 3, 9)` i.e., elements not found in either one.